Angular Memory leak: simple input resulting in detached nodes
I have generated angular app for the test purpose, created Page1 and Page2 components.
is the code for Page2
TypeScript (Page2Component)

import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-page2',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [],
    templateUrl: './page2.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./page2.component.scss'] // Corrected to `styleUrls`
})
export class Page2Component implements OnDestroy {
    inputText: string = '';

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // Clear the input text or perform other cleanup actions
        this.inputText = '';
    }
}


HTML (page2.component.html)

<p>page2 works!</p>
<div>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputText" />
</div>

Steps to reproduce the issue:

Navigate to page2, type something in the input.
Navigate to page1, take snapshot.

I see page2 in detached nodes, cause I have typed in the input field. If I do not type in the field then it's not present.
Please someone explain me why typing inside the input causing detached nodes? I don't have any subscriptions and it is just above simple components, thanks in advance
I was not expecting memory leak
